# Does coding really require logic or some part of it is a copy-paste game?

Tags: coding-style, logic, copy-paste, nlp-question-answering

I am new to programming and I have some doubts about it. I have read hundreds of time that coding is really mind dependent or it is logic game and critical thinking is a must have skill for it, but somehow I wonder if that is really true. For e.g. I find problems on coding practice sites such as hackerearth interesting and I get pretty sure that it(coding) is a "math oriented logic puzzle" but whenever I see, for example, people asking code for "how to create a progress bar in html", "how to code auto fill otp in android app", "how to ask permission for location in android app" or "how to create circle in pygame(a Python library)", I really think that real world industry solutions are not "logic puzzles" on hackerearth but a copy paste or fairly say, the invented wheel that really gets used again and again. And that's what you require as a skill or are asked to do in industry so where is the "real brainstorming or logic"? I get really confused over this. So is coding really "logic" or "a reusable plastic polythene" that one generation of programmers pass to next and that to next and so forth? I mean somebody at first time really must have used logic in past(in examples that I talked about or like them) or were they really created for the "copy paste chains" or say for standard use? Can they not be designed in different logic?

Note:-

1. I have used "coding" and "programming" interchangeably here 
   and really don't want the old discussion here, so please 
   answer specifically and comprehensively!
2. Please don't vote it for closing citing it "as too broad" because 
   superuser is, I think, somewhat "not programming oriented" and it 
   can be best answered here despite some generality of it.

Comment: Programming is knowing the tools (language, APIs) and using them. In real life you will barely find pure puzzle tasks, since your customers want an app, a website or something else

Comment: @Raildex So copy-paste theory true?

Comment: Sometimes yes. But you will have to adapt snippets into your own environment

Answer (score 0):

The puzzle is the part where you get diffrent snippets and change them so you can use them together to create something.